# why imageview not showing inside cardview?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, cardview

I am developing a new app but image view not showing inside card view I want to know exactly where I am making a mistake
below my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/companyWebsite"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/companyName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyWebsite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Company Website"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/companyLogo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/companyLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="286dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="286dp"
            android:text="Company Name"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/companyLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My current UI from the real device:

[image: my current UI from real device]

below my RecyclerviewAdapter class where  I have downloaded image view using glide and implemented ImageView logic
below my RecyclerviewAdapter class where  I have downloaded image view using glide and implemented ImageView logic

```
  class SpectrumAdapter(
        private val spectrumResponse: ArrayList <SpectrumResponseItem>
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpectrumViewHolder>() {
    
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SpectrumViewHolder {
    
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.spectrum_list, parent, false)
            return SpectrumViewHolder(view)
    
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return spectrumResponse.size
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SpectrumViewHolder, position: Int) {
            return holder.bind(spectrumResponse[position])
        }
    }
    
    
        class SpectrumViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    
            private val companyLogo: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyLogo)
            private val companyName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyName)
            private val companyWebsite: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyWebsite)
    
            fun bind(spectrum: SpectrumResponseItem) {
                Glide.with(itemView.context).load(spectrum.logo).into(companyLogo)
    
                companyName.text = spectrum.company
                companyWebsite.text = spectrum.website
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: How are you applying the image to the imageview, using glide? picasso?

Comment: I am using glide you need adapter code as well

Comment: @JakeB, I am using glide do you need adapter code as well

Comment: Yes post your complete code including where glide is applying the image

Comment: @JakeB Ihave posted please checkit

Comment: Is the value for ```spectrum.logo``` a correct url to an image?

Comment: http://placehold.it/32x32 yes this image url

Comment: @JakeB it is correcturl

Comment: what doyou think mainproblem

Comment: Test it with the url of an image from google, rule out at it isnt a url problem

Comment: @JakeB url image from google is showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219205/discussion-between-edgar-davids-and-jakeb).